# Why copy function is not working properly here?

Tags: python-3.x, list

why matrix list is getting changed here even temp list was created using copy function, it should not be changed while making changes in temp list but here matrix list got changes with temp list.

python code is given below:

```py
matrix = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

temp = matrix.copy()
temp[0][1] = 69

print('temp: ',temp)
print('matrix: ',matrix)

# here output is coming as:

temp:  [[1, 69, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
matrix:  [[1, 69, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). In short, use `deepcopy`.

Comment: You already got the answer ^^^.  To see the data structure - can try to run here https://pythontutor.com/